# Ajax js and rails code not synced destroy.js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this bit of code sitting within my destroy.js.erb to perform an ajax request to delete some object...

The <% @client.destroy %> bit is run no matter what, and will delete the client no matter what is clicked.

```
    callback: function(e) {
        if (e === true) {
           return $('#edit_client_<%= @client.id %>').parent().remove();
           <% @client.destroy %>
           console.log(e);
        }else if (e === false){
           console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this in an elegant way?

Comment: it's the variable that is sent back from the dialog. It returns 'true' or 'false'. The console.log's confirm that the if statement is working properly because they return the correct variables.

Comment: it's a js.erb file so first rails code will get executed. Use if else depending on rails variable not js

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. The things is.. the rails code that is executing depends on the users input which is sent back in from js.

Comment: what code you are sending? Why not send that code with ajax call? Save that in instance variable inside your action and then check for that variable in js.erb file

Comment: Well, what I'm going to try is this: have a listener check for the delete button that is clicked, and give the dialog there. Depending on what is clicked, the destroy action will be called or not. Then in destroy.js I can perform the removal of the client form the page via ajax.

Comment: I think what you can do is create a button by click on it you can launch your dialog and then instead of using a delete verb use post verb and send it to your custom action with the parameters that you want to send and then according to your parameters you can perform your action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your file ends in `js.erb`. This is part of the *asset pipeline*, and it means that the `ERB` (Rails) bit runs before any of the JS (in fact, the JS isn't even run on the server, so you can't really reverse the order of the naming to get it to run on the server).

The simplest solution would be to add a data attribute containing the client's ID or something similar to the button that's clicked, and using that ID rather than the Ruby to generate the ID.

**Re: first comment**
Same thing applies. That ERB code will be run regardless of the Javascript `if`, because the ERB processor doesn't understand/care about your JS `if`. Best solution would be to send an AJAX request to your server, where you do the `destroy` in your controller. That also has the benefit of cleanly separating your frontend and backend.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! It seems I didn't specify my issue clearly enough so I edited it at the end. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: ^ Edited, but same thing applies

Comment: Great. So this has evolved into a new question, which is how do I send the delete request from jquery haha.

Comment: Short answer: Use AJAX. If your `@client` is a resource, it should be pretty straightforward. If you want to turn that into another SO question and link it, I'll help you there :)

Comment: Yeah I figured it out yesterday. Thanks for the offer though!!